# Где в PreferenceStore хранятся настройки по-умолчанию?

Tags: java, swt

Всем привет!

Недавно возникла задача доработать приложение на **SWT** и **JFace**. Есть такой класс
[PreferenceStore](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fpreference%2FPreferenceStore.html), который хранит настройки в обычном текстовом файле.
В этом классе есть возможность задать настройки по-умолчанию (методы **setDefault**), а также изменять текущие настройки (методы **setValue**).

После того, как значение настройки было изменено, есть возможность откатится к настройке по-умолчанию.
При этом в файле с настройками хранятся только текущие настройки (настроек по-умолчанию там нет).

Собственно вопрос: где же хранятся настройки по-умолчанию при использовании класса **PreferenceStore**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Собственно, ответ был на поверхности.
Они "вшиваются" в исходники.